# How to repeat values in case of null values on left join

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a calendar, and a table with rates. In the table with the rates, there are no values existing for days in the weekend. I'm trying to join the two, in order to have a table where there is a rate for all days, and I need the rates in the weekend to be the latest available rate. Instad of it showing NULL values, as it would when you make a left join and the record doesn't exist, it should just take the latest available, repeating the previous value.

I have the below code, which works, but it takes 2 min to do on 7,397 rows, which is way too long.

Does anyone know a faster way to get the same results?

```
SELECT
c.CalendarID, 
MAX(r.RateID)

FROM Dim_Calendar c

LEFT JOIN Dim_Rates r ON r.RateDate <= c.CalendarID
```

What I get without <= and just an = is the following

```
CalendarID | RateID
20131001   | 2
20131002   | 3
20131003   | 4
20131004   | 5
20131005   | NULL
20131006   | NULL
20131007   | 6
```

And this is the desired table:

```
CalendarID | RateID
20131001   | 2
20131002   | 3
20131003   | 4
20131004   | 5
20131005   | 5
20131006   | 5
20131007   | 6
```

Comment: Something seems odd about the timing. That query should come back in seconds if your tables are small. How many records are returned from the calendar dimension? Can you describe the indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LAG()` window function:

```
SELECT c.CalendarID,
  COALESCE(
    r.RateID,
    LAG(r.RateID, 1) OVER (ORDER BY c.CalendarID),
    LAG(r.RateID, 2) OVER (ORDER BY c.CalendarID)
  ) RateID
FROM Dim_Calendar c LEFT JOIN Dim_Rates r 
ON r.RateDate = c.CalendarID
ORDER BY c.CalendarID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60137522e7cb57d47408ddcd9341b7da).
Results:

```
> CalendarID | RateID
> ---------: | :-----
>   20131001 | 2     
>   20131002 | 3     
>   20131003 | 4     
>   20131004 | 5     
>   20131005 | 5     
>   20131006 | 5     
>   20131007 | 6
```

Comment: Nice solution to fill the weekends gaps, but if there is a monday or friday holiday it would still show a gap. Just to be safe you could feed the coalesce function with a few more values.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a correlated subquery to fill the gaps:

```
SELECT
    c.CalendarID, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 r.RateID FROM Dim_Rates r
     WHERE r.RateDate <= c.CalendarID AND r.RateID IS NOT NULL
     ORDER BY r.RateDate DESC) AS RateID
FROM Dim_Calendar c
ORDER BY c.CalendarID;
```

This query can be improved by using the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON Dim_Rates (RateDate, RateID);
```

Comment: Hi Tim. It works, but it still takes quite a while to complete  :-(

Comment: Try adding an appropriate index, q.v. my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you need to check for proper and covering indexing. It appears you are running a against a DW DB and if that is the case then you can replace the CTE with indexed temp tables if the esitmated row count approximation is way off in the query plan.

```
;WITH NormalizedData AS
(
    SELECT
        RateID,CalendarID,
        VirtualGroupID = SUM(LastRecordBeforeGap) OVER (ORDER BY CalendarID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT RateID,CalendarID,
        LastRecordBeforeGap = CASE WHEN LEAD(RateID) OVER(ORDER BY CalendarID) IS NULL AND RateID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM
            Dim_Calendar  c
            LEFT JOIN Dim_Rates  r ON r.RateDate = c.CalendarID
    )AS x
)

SELECT 
    RateID = ISNULL(RateID, SUM(RateID) OVER(PARTITION BY VirtualGroupID)),
    CalendarID 
FROM 
    NormalizedData
```